# Как найти запись в одной таблице по значению из другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

как по project_id найти запись в столбце client_id?

Client_contacts

| id | Project_id | name | telegram |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | nick | 18238323 |

Projects

| id | name | description | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | proj | descr | 1 |

Comment: Если вы знаете изначально project_id, то просто селектом из Projects с фильтрацией по id. Вы что-то недоговариваете по условиям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
select client_id
from Projects as p
inner join Client_contacts as c
on p.id = c.Project_id
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).